# Do I need to add implementation("androidx.room:room-ktx: 2.5.1") when I want to use Kotlin Extensions and Coroutines support for Room?

Tags: android, android-studio, groovy

The  Code A comes from https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room#groovy

The  Code B comes from https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room#kts

If I need to use  Kotlin Extensions and Coroutines support for Room with Groovy settings, do I need to add `implementation("androidx.room:room-ktx:$room_version")` in Code A ?

**Code A**

```
dependencies {
    def room_version = "2.5.1"

    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
    annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"

    // To use Kotlin annotation processing tool (kapt)
    kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"
    // To use Kotlin Symbol Processing (KSP)
    ksp "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"

    ...
}
```

**Code B**

```
dependencies {
    val room_version = "2.5.1"

    implementation("androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version")
    annotationProcessor("androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version")

    // To use Kotlin annotation processing tool (kapt)
    kapt("androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version")
    // To use Kotlin Symbol Processing (KSP)
    ksp("androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version")

    // optional - Kotlin Extensions and Coroutines support for Room
    implementation("androidx.room:room-ktx:$room_version")

   ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should add implementation("androidx.room:room-ktx:$room_version") to Room use it with Kotlin Coroutines

Answer (score 0):

Yes, additionally you should remove kapt as it slows builds down and has been replaced with ksp. This is how it should be done currently (version 2.6.1).

```
val room_version = "2.6.1"
implementation("androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version")
annotationProcessor("androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version")
implementation("androidx.room:room-ktx:$room_version")//KTX Extensions/Coroutines for Room
ksp("androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version")
```